# How do I fix annoying quoted-printable emails sent with PHP?

Tags: php, sendmail

I am sending emails like this:

```
$message = "Hello<br/>Something else here.<br/>Bye!";
$html_msg = '<html><head>
             <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
             </head><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
             '.$message.'
             </body>
             </html>';

$header = "Date: " . $mail_date . "\n".
          "Return-Path: " . $from_email . "\n".
          "To: " . $to . "\n".
          "From: Me <me@me.com>\n".
          "Subject: " . $subject . "\n".
          "MIME-Version: 1.0\n".
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n".
          sprintf("Content-Type: %s; charset=\"%s\"","text/html","utf-8")."\n\n";

$output = sprintf("%s -oi -t", "/usr/sbin/sendmail");

    if(!@$mail = popen($output, "w")) {
                echo "Error!";
    }

    fputs($mail, $header);
    fputs($mail, $html_msg);

    $result = pclose($mail) >> 8 & 0xFF;

    if($result != 0) {
                echo "Error!";
    }
```

Now, it executes correctly but when I check the HTML code of the email received, it's full of `quoted-printable` content like:

```
<html><head>
=09=09=09=09=09=09=09 <meta http-equiv=3D"content-type" content=3D"text/htm=
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why do you care what's in the source code of HTML mail? It will be rendered properly when it's viewed. Anyway, you probably have to fix that in your `sendmail` configuration.

Comment: If you need help with that, try asking on Serverfault.com or SuperUser.com.

Comment: I was worried images would not show up correctly if it adds the "3D" to every tag...

Comment: `=3D` is the quoted-printable representation of the `=` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=09 is a tab symbol.

In your code you must be using tabs to create a spacing in front of the closing head tag and these tabs show up as =09

```
$html_msg = '<html><head>
             <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Try to rewrite as:

```
$html_msg = '<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Note that there in no leading spaces/tabs in front of second line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes perfect sense. Any ideas why it's adding the 3D before each `"`? I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me!

Comment: It can't use a regular `=` because that's the prefix for hex codes in quoted-printable.